# Query firestore collection once and use document data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have this function to go through a firestore collection and return the document data into an Observable. Then using the observable i want to loop through the documents and add these documents into another collection in firestore.

For some reason everytime this collection provided changes, this method gets called. I only want it called once though from a specific component. Any help would be appreciated.

```
addProductsToOrder(){

 this.myCartProducts = this.afs.collection(`/users/DfyEg7WwnPsz73ln0Ptd/mycart/l4c2QOQ4rb8sivOtXkSb/products`)
      .snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions=>{
        return actions.map(a=>{
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;

          return data;
        })
      }));


      //i have tried subscribe as well as forEach
      this.myCartProducts.forEach(val =>{
        console.log(val)
        //over here i'll add code to add this val into another firebase collection.
      })

  }
```

Comment: Have a look at: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1413

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FB not natively support the .get() method, but you do have two options.

Use the underlying reference

```
constructor(afs: AngularFirestore) {
 afs.collection('items').ref.get();
 }
```

Use .take(1)

```
// import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
constructor(afs: AngularFirestore) {
  afs.collection('items').valueChanges().pipe(take(1));
}
```

by @davideast

Comment: how does the ref.get() work exactly? i have to store it as a DocumentReference?

Comment: It pulls the exact item within a document. So if you had data: { id: 1, name: myname }; then you go can do something like this.firestoredb.collection('nameofcollection').get('id').subscribe((x) => { console.log(x); };